# My site on mobile version is not giving responsive view

Tags: css, mobile

I have a website that l use Book your travel theme

lately l realized that my site is giving a widescreen on mobile version for some reason!

l have only made an update for the plugins 2 days ago l dont remember having that problem after l updated the plugin

My main site is in Arabic language and should be viewing right to left but it’s giving a wide screen from the left side on posts pages
here is an example

https://turkiyaholidays.com/%d9%81%d9%86%d8%a7%d8%af%d9%82-%d8%aa%d9%82%d8%b3%d9%8a%d9%85/

Looking for your urgent help

thank you

Comment: You will need to consult your theme's support channels or a generalized WordPress community.

Comment: Where shall l dind a  generalized WordPress community

Comment: Facebook and Discord both have several. I'm sure they can be found on other communications platforms like Telegram and Slack as well. There's forums around as well, but I don't know any off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

following your main page HTML elements :

**#ez-toc-container .ez-toc-title-container .ez-toc-title-toggle #uniform-item #item**

You will see that checkbox(#item) element have a CSS left value equal to -999em

So all you need is to reset that value (that won't effect the design, but it will help fixing your out-screen layout issue)

You can do it adding this CSS code via the wordpress customizer page

Page Link:
https://YOURDOMAIN/wp-admin/customize.php

replace "YOURDOMAIN" with your domain

Then > Additional CSS and then paste the following code and then click on Save :

```
#ez-toc-container .ez-toc-title-container .ez-toc-title-toggle #uniform-item #item {
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code I have pasted the code and it's working just fine
But where can l find the CSS code that contains the -999em so l can delete it or change it to 0
It would be better than adding a code to force that CSS code to disable 
And thanx for your help anyway :)

Comment: Glad that i could help.
You will find the CSS "left" value in the "easy-table-of-contents" plugin files :

wp-content/plugins/easy-table-of-contents/assets/css/screen.min.css

Line : 22

But i don't recommended to change it from the plugin files because any future updates will remove your changes.